# Is it possible to show actual progress from Async Method in Node.Js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am now showing a simple .gif image of moving progress lines on html user interface. Which will not show the actual progress (in percentage) happening at the server. I am retrieving data from a server(MongoDB) of lower bandwidth.

I have two choices:

1.To show simple loading/progress .gif image on user interface and then after completion of server end process pop a message to user saying that it is completed.

2.Parallel update can be shown in percentage to user as and when there is a considerable progress at server end.

There are some node-upload-progress, node-progress. But how to use them with long running MongoDB query. (instead of file upload for node-upload-progress).
How can I achieve the (2nd choice) show parallel progress on UI, is it possible to show actual progress from Async Method in Node.Js?

Comment: @juzerali See question is whether to show actual progress happening at server end using socket.io or its better to simply show some animated progress bar till the server processing completes... If you still didn't understand.. let me know....  :-0

Comment: @JuzerAli: What is you misunderstanding with question please let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [socket.io](http://socket.io) for this purpose. Here is a demo app ([link](https://github.com/dotcloud/socket.io-on-dotcloud)) which I had referred.

So emitting an event on every 5% completing of process from server end and listening at client side to update percentage on a progress bar.

[Techie](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/techie) guys are most welcome to answer if any other efficient alternatives are in existence with Node.js to achieve the same